# Non-isomorphic connected vertex-transitive graphs on $\omega$

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Are there $2^{\aleph_0}$ pairwise non-isomorphic connected [vertex-transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex-transitive_graph) graphs $G$ with $V(G) = \omega$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. In particular, there are continuously many pairwise non-quasi-isometric Cayley graphs with countably infinite vertex set. A proof of this is in the paper *Continuously many quasi-isometry classes of 2-generator groups* by Bowditch.

Comment: I think this result is originally due to Grigorchuk (maybe be with 4 rather than 2 generators).

Comment: This follows also e.g. from the existence of Cayley graphs with a wide range of growth behaviors, which is a quasi-isometric invariant.

Comment: @M.Winter yes this is precisely Grigorchuk's argument.